# Content overlaps in Ionic 1 app for IOS version 11 and above

Tags: ios, css, cordova, ionic-framework, ios11

I have a app built using **Cordova, Ionic V1 and AngularJS V1** and in a particular control that is **displaying date**, content overlaps to the previous value. This issue is observed only in **IOS 11.4.1** (latest release). In the previous version IOS the control was working properly.

I have attached the screen shot

[image]

After inspecting in XCode I found out that this is a issue which is caused by **display: block** property. So I tried changing the value of display, most of the values says unsupported in IOS and which works is **display: -webkit-box-**. But when I add that all the contents move to extreme left side that is Month, Date and Year values which I have highlighted in the image.

And below is the code

```
this.selectDate = function (date) {
        if (this.isDisabled(date)) return;
        this.selectedDate = angular.copy(date);
        this.selectedDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        this.tempDate = angular.copy(this.selectedDate);
    };
```

Template code

```
<div class=row>
  <div class="col datepicker-day-of-month" 
       ng-click="datepickerCtrl.changeType(\'date\')"> 
       {{datepickerCtrl.selectedDate | date: \'d\'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code is part of ionic-datepicker [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datepicker-for-ionic).

The date content works **properly on Android** has **issue only in IOS V 11.4.1.**

Thanks :)

Comment: Might be, raise an issue in the Github repository of ionic-datepicker.

Comment: I checked in there issue, there last response was in back 2016. So posted here.

Comment: Using Xcode, you can debug. Seems like the CSS class used in date picker is not supported in IOS 11.4.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Yes I did inspect. I found that display:block is causing this issue. I tried changing the value for that property only display: -webkit-box- property works. But what happens is content what i have highlighted in the image moves to extreme left side. Do you know any equivalent for display: -webkit-box- ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the display property value which does not support for IOS 11.4.1.

```
display: block;
```

The above property does not work in the latest version of IOS.

So I changed the value of the display property

```
display: -webkit-inline-box !important;
text-align: -webkit-center !important;
```

text-align is used to align the div elements at the center.

This solution works for both Android and IOS.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but I faced something similar issue. Please try to replace `<div>` with `<span>` and see if it works:

```
<div class=row>
  <span class="col datepicker-day-of-month" 
       ng-click="datepickerCtrl.changeType(\'date\')"> 
       {{datepickerCtrl.selectedDate | date: \'d\'}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Also instead of `display: block` use `display: inline`.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested. Its the same as the image I have added in the question.

Comment: @ShashankHS It would be nice if you can create a working code snippet of your requirement using JSFiddle or Plunker etc.